# map <S-TAB> to to tab key

Tags: vim, supertab

I'm using the vim plugin [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) to map the `<TAB>` key to autocompletion, I however, sometimes want the old tab functionality (to indent at the end of a word), and wanted to map it to `<S-TAB>`, but I can't seem to make it work.

The documentation states there is `g:SuperTabMappingTabLiteral`, which I can set, to get the old tab functionality back. I set it to `let g:SuperTabMappingTabLiteral = '<s-tab>'` but that doesn't seem to work either.

The other questions on SO are about how to get a literal tab character with supertab enabled, **I don't want a literal tab**.

Comment: Do you use Gvim or Vim?

Comment: Vim on tty/terminal, on Linux.

Comment: You got probably problem with you terminal hijacking <S-tab> key. Google how to make it work. It depends on your terminal and then just place inoremap <S-tab> <tab> in your .vimrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this just after your plugin manager

```
runtime! plugin/supertab.vim
```

then

```
inoremap <s-tab> <tab>
```

should work. Just tested it in my vimrc, the problem was than supertab overrides the mapping.